# Power supply for stepper motor driver board

Tags: gpio, power-supply, dc-motor

I'm doing a project where I wish to use 5 stepper motors simultaneously. I've ordered these (with driver board included) https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B015RQ97W8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B (one with 2x20 pinout).

I've successfully wired two of them with the driver board and I'm controlling them successfully with GPIO. I followed this tutorial which worked first try with them https://keithweaverca.medium.com/controlling-stepper-motors-using-python-with-a-raspberry-pi-b3fbd482f886 However, as the Pi only has two 5V pins, as far as I can tell in my complete and utter electric noobness, to control the other three I'll need some other power supply, then hook up GPIO and ground pins (for which the 2x20 has enough remaining since I only need 4 GPIO pins and 1 ground pin per driver board) like normal.

Is this correct?

If so, are there any recommendations for external power supply for the motor (or if I can DIY one from a battery or something)?

I also have breadboards available if I need to do anything with them.

Comment: I've taken a brief look at the links posted in your question. Unfortunately, but as is typical for most Chinese-made components sold on Amazon, there is no data sheet - no specifications. I'm afraid I can't help you without some data. If you can find the data, please edit your question to add it. In the meantime, I've deleted my answer. It does seem to be a fairly common kit, so perhaps there are some videos or "How-To-Blogs" online that will be useful. Also, check out [joan's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133348/83790) as it appears he may have experience with this kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect more than one stepper driver to the same 5V and ground pin.

The simplest way is to connect a wire between 5V and a breadboard power rail (red) and another wire between ground and a breadboard ground rail (blue).  Then connect the stepper drivers to those rails.

Comment: If I do this, are there any concerns I should have about the amount of current the stepper drivers need or anything like that?

Comment: As long as there is enough to power the Pi, any peripherals you have connected, and the stepper drivers, you are good to go.  I have often driven 5 ULN2803 based stepper drivers for those small steppers from the Pi.

Comment: A week later and your advice worked! Thanks so much!